# Embedded video beamer

Tags: beamer, media9

I use the following code to embed a video in a beamer presentation

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{}{}

\centering
\includemedia[
  width=0.4\linewidth,
  totalheight=0.225\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
  addresource=video.avi,
  flashvars={
    %important: same path as in `addresource'
    source=video.avi
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, despite the code compiles without errors, when I try to open the presentation through *okular* the video doesn't show up. What am I missing?

Comment: Flashplayer maybe

Comment: In fact, for me, the video plays in Okular (using an existing video file, such as `example-movie.mp4` from pkg `mwe`). My Okular version is 21.04.1. There are no player controls shown, though.